# CakePHP reference this controller with $this

Tags: cakephp

Using CakePHP how can you get a reference to this controller without specifying it's name?

Comment: is this for a component? you should also always specify the cake version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I needed to reference this controller to create the following public function.
But the dogmatic69 way is much nicer.

```
// Controller/AppController.php

public function dumpData() {
    if(!Configure::read('debug') > 2)
        throw new Exception(".dumpData() can only be accessed in debug mode.");

    // $controller = Inflector::singularize($this->name);
    // $data = $this->$controller->find('first');
    $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('first');
    die(debug($data));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you ever want to reference a controller by name? Cake only ever has one controller loaded, you should not be loading other controllers in a single request. 1 request == 1 controller.

If you want to referent the model without the name, the default model name is in `$this->modelClass`

$this->{$this->modelClass}->method();

The accepted answer (if it is a **model** you want) is **wrong**.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('People');

    public function method() {
        $this->{$this->modelClass}->method(); // works

        $controller = Inflector::singularize($this->name);
        $this->$controller->someMethod(); // fatal error
    }
}
```